# Laravel protecting routes with verified middleware not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've implemented Laravel-5.8 email verification following this tutorial: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification.
I'm trying to protect few routes from email unverified users as like below:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['verified']], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/backend', 'DashboardController@backend')->name('backend');
});
```

But I can access to `dashboard` without verifying my email address.

How can I prevent this access without verifying email?

Comment: please add your verified middleware code and steps you done to trace where is your problem

Comment: I did not add verified middleware seperately, as I followed the tutorial from https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification. Do I need to add 'verified middleware?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is generally a pretty simple thing to get up and running, you may have a small mistake in your application somewhere, so here's a checklist to quickly go over.

1. Does the user you're testing have a null `email_verified_at` field in the database?
2. Have you added `implements MustVerifyEmail` within the user model?

`class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail`

3. Did you set verify to true in your `routes/web.php?`

`Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`

You've added the middleware properly to the routes, so that isn't the issue.

Other than that we don't have much information to go off.